# encrypting web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, asp.net-4.0

Here is my c# code :

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.config");

ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("appSettings");
section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;        
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
string sectionXml = section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
```

I need to encrypt `web.config` programatically, but it gives me error:

> A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.

Comment: On what **line** does this error happen??

Comment: config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on the `~/web.config`, the `OpenWebConfiguration` needs the full application path, not the name of the web.config as appears on web.

Try this (tested and working for the opening):

```
OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

or (base on msdn sample code)

```
OpenWebConfiguration(/web.config);
```

or even call it with **null**, as [MSDN notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx).